# PHP - Edit classes for success result

Tags: php

How to get in php data from 3 classes and 1 class extended ABCD result. 
Can somebody please help fix my code ?

```
class Common{
     public function __construct(){
          $this->data = 'A';
     }
     public function getData(){
          return $data;
     }
}

class SetOne extends Common{
     protected $data;
     public function __construct(){
          $this->data = 'B';
     }
}

class SetTwo extends Common{
     protected $data;
     public function __construct(){
          $this->data .= 'C';
          $obj = new SetOne();
     }
}

class SetTree extends Common{
     protected $data;
     public function __construct(){
          $this->data .= 'D';
          $obj = new SetTwo();
     }
}

$obj = new SetTree();
echo $obj->getData(); // I want to get the result: **ABCD**
```

I really do not know how. :-( Thank you for your help.

Comment: Problem #1 in `Common`: `return $this->data;`; Problem #2 in `Common`: you should define the $data property here, not in all the child properties

Comment: Problem #3 Why instantiate new parent classes in every child when they ___inherit___

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be

```
class Common{
    protected $data;
    public function __construct(){
         $this->data = 'A';
    }
    public function getData(){
        return $this->data;
    }
}

class SetOne extends Common{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->data .= 'B';
    }
}

class SetTwo extends SetOne{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->data .= 'C';
    }
}

class SetTree extends SetTwo{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->data .= 'D';
    }
}

$obj = new SetTree();
echo $obj->getData(); // I want to get the result: **ABCD**
```